# On a functional equation

Tags: real-analysis

Find all functions $f : ]0 , +\infty [ \to ]0 , +\infty[$ not necessary continuous, verifying:

1. $f(xf(x)) = f(1 + x^2)$ , for all $x > 0$,
2. $f(x)$ tends to $+\infty$ when $x$ tends to $+\infty$.

Note that:

- $f(x) = x + \frac{1}{x}$ is a solution.
- This solution is unique if we can prove that $f$ is injective.
- The equation $f(x) = 1$ has no solution when $x > 0$.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: We can't prove that $f$ must be injective, because $x+\frac1x$ is not injective.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path I think that won't be problem as on the RHS $1+x^2$ is greater than 1, and in [1,$\infty$]  x+ 1/x is injective

Comment: @PerelmanJr I guess if you manage to prove that $xf(x)\ge1$ for all $x$ and that $f$ must be injective on $[1,\infty)$, then you can do that. However, these things are not quite at hand right now.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.- We have for $x\gt 1$, $$f(x)=f(\sqrt{x-1}f(\sqrt{x-1}))$$ It seems that the obvious solution is the only one. In particular, knowing $f(x)=a$ we have a geometrical way to build $f(\sqrt{x-1})$ which is equal to 
$\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{x-1}}$. For example you do have
$$\begin{cases}f(f(1))=f(2)\\f(2f(2))=f(5)\\f(5f(5))=f(26)\\...\\...\\f(\sqrt{n-1}f(\sqrt{n-1}))=f(n)\end{cases}$$